# Show $[Y, Z]$ vanishes at all points of the image if $Z$ vanishes at all points of the image

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $F\in C^{\infty}(M,N)$ be a smooth map of manifolds. Suppose $X\sim_F Y$, and let $Z\in \mathfrak{X}(N)$ be a vector field vanishing at all points of the image $F(M)\subset$ N, show that $[Y,Z]$ vanishes at all points of the image.

This is a question from practice test. Now I am having trouble starting on this question... So what is the condition $[X,Y]$ for? It seems to me that $X$ has nothing to do with the conclusion that we are trying to prove. And how do we use the condition $Z$ vanishes on the image $F(M)$? Any hints on this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let $X'$ be the zero vector field. Then $0 = F_{*}(X') = Z \circ F$ so $X'$ and $Z$ are $F$-related. Since $X$ and $Y$ are $F$-related, we get that $[X,X'] = 0$ is $F$-related to $[Y,Z]$ which precisely means that
$$ 0 = F_{*}(0) = F_{*}([X,X']) = [Y,Z] \circ F $$

so $[Y,Z]$ vanishes in the image of $F$.